# Isolating 220V AC from low voltage DC on the PCB

Tags: pcb-design, isolation

Below picture is the rectifier section of design on the PCB:

[image]

The space between AC and DC voltage is ~2 cm, except at the bottom that I put four M3 holes which I'm going to drill and connect them to each other.

The relay control part is going to connect to an opto-isolator and from there to the MCU.

Is the taken precaution steps enough for isolating AC from DC? any tips for improvement?

Comment: Are you sure the pinout of the relais is correct? The pinout with the switched terminal right between the coil terminals looks ehm, undesirable to me.

Comment: @marcelm Yes it's correct, the actual relay NC and NO pins are reversed.

Comment: For PCB voltage spacing rules see: https://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html

Comment: Maybe post the schematic to allow better understanding of what the parts are doing and their separation requirements.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it safe, most likely not.

When you have AC Line and low voltage on the same board, you need to have a clear separation of the two sections. Here it is not the case.

The AC side and the low voltage side need to be isolated from each other, and from the circuit, it seems not to be the case. You need to have optical or galvanic isolator between the two sides.

It is recommended to use cutout through the board to separate the section and without having any trace going to either section. This has several advantages from having a clear boundary, to avoid having PCB defect that might short AC to the low voltage side.

Few example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how do I control the relay then? the coil pins are right next to the AC line...

Comment: There are tons of devices for galvanic coupling available. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/isolators/digital-isolators/901?k=digital%20isolator

Comment: I mean the space between the relay common pin and coils are just few mm, is that going to be a problem too? is there an special kind of relay that have coils pin away from the contact pins?

Comment: Yes I think that's quite a problem. Depending on the current you need. Note that since you use a transformer after your relay, relay isn't a good solution as the induction of the transformer will arc the relay and the relay lifetime is going to be relatively short. You can use a triac circuit to switch on/ off http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/triacs2.htm this is going to be more robust and probably cheaper